# Basic Discord.js bot not going online

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to creat a discord js bot and followed a tutorial (i cant seem to find it again) I also found some other posts on Stack Overflow but i tried them and they also didn't work (its probably a stupid error because i am a beginner):

```
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits } from 'discord.js';
const client = new Client({ 
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds
    ] 
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.login('I have the wright token inserted');
```

It doesn't console log it or show the green online dot on Discord.
Please Help.

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error message in your console after starting the bot?

Comment: no the terminal is just empty

Comment: you're using typescript?

Comment: no basic JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that I'm not using ES module version, but a CommonJS.

You didn't specify which version you are using. However, on the version `14.4.1`
the standard **online-based-code** should look like this:

```js
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const { token } = require("./config.json");

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.once(Events.ClientReady, (readyClient) => {
  console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${readyClient.user.tag}`);
});

client.login(token);
```

Of course, keep in mind, that `config.json` should look like this:

```json
{
"token" : "token_goes_here"
}
```

I assume, you didn't export events correctly.